# Kafka Mirror Connect Error trying to forward REST request

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am trying to connect two Kafka instances for an active-active state with mirror maker. After starting the mirror maker it works for a few minutes with replicating the topics and then spit out the following error

[image]

Any ideas on what would be causing this problem? Thank you

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58994113/2308683